# Override/Change final class method implementing interface java

Tags: java, final, overriding

**Java** - I have an Interface say InterfaceA that has three methods - method1, method2, method3.

A **final** class implements this interface. 
This class and interface are in a Jar and their implementations are unknown.

The Method method2 of class is not working as per expectations.
What are possible ways in which i can have the right implementation/override this method.

Comment: can you please add some code, clarify expected behaviour and tell us what error message are you getting? :)

Comment: If it is not behaving according to its documentation, you can try and start a bug ticket at the manufacturer's website. Apart from that you would need to wrap the class in a custom class implementing the interface delegating the other two methods and implementing the one in question to your needs. But this will only work if the method does not change some internal state. And of course it has a very bad smell ...

Answer (score 5):

## In Java you cannot extend final classes.

---

So the only way is to code your own class with

- your own the method implementation
- call the final class methods in other cases

```
class Third implements TheInterfaceInQuestion {

    FinalClass fc;

    public Third() {
       fc = new FinalClass();
    }

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        // call final class implementation
        fc.method1();
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        // new implementation
    }

    @Override
    public void method3() {
        // call final class implementation
        fc.method3();
    }

}
```